# Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm new to Spring Data MongoDB.

I'm trying to use `@DBRef` to refer a `Document` (Comments) from another `Document` (News) with **spring-data-mongodb-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar**.

To make things easy, I'm not passing anything as parameters for the rest call. The `Comments` collection exist in the database. I'm getting the following exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
>   path [/news] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.mongodb.DBRef.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V] with
>   root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.mongodb.DBRef.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

The following is my code:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Comments{
    @Id
    private String id;

private String Comment;

public Comments(String comment){
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.comment = comment
}
     //getters & setters
}


import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class News{

@Id
private String id;
private String Title;
private String summary;
@DBRef
private List<Comments> comments;

public News(){
}

public News(String title, String summary){
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.title = title;
    this.summary = summary;

}

    //getters and setters
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/test")
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger =                   LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/createnews", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createNews() {
    logger.info("createNews method started");
    News news = new News("News Title", "News summary");
    List<Comments> commentList = new ArrayList<Comments>();
    Comments comments = new Comments("News Comments");
    commentList.add( comments );
    news.setComments( commentList );    

    logger.info("createNews method ended");

    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I am unable to use `@DBRef` with **spring-data-mongodb-1.7.0.RELEASE.jar**.

I'm looking for advice from the experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for response Ayano. What I want is to store as Object not as Embedded Document. Yes, Embedded document works

Answer (score 0):

**Just Delete the "@DBRef".**
You can't use DBRef to link a document to the list.
Spring data mongodb would transfer the List of your domain class as a child array in the document(As Embedded Documents).
Like this:

```
{
   _id: 100,
   Title: "food",
   summary: "xyz",
   Comments: [ { id: "111", Comment: "shipping" },  { id: "111", Comment: "shipping" } ]
}
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-embedded-documents for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do summarize your findings in answer for benefit of future readers and in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving your entities. You will first have to save the referred entity and then the parent entity.

```
News news = new News("News Title", "News summary");
Comments comments = new Comments("News Comments");
news.setComments( Arrays.asList(comments) );    

mongoTemplate.save(comments);
mongoTemplate.save(news);
```

Comment: Yes, the child object is saved first before the parent object.

Comment: Can you share your repository config and how you are saving  your entities? Do you see your comments being saved in mongo, since as i understand your transaction is failing after saving the comments and while saving the news ?